# In the edit form of Django CRUD application the existing data is not showing correctly in the fields

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and trying to build a Django CRUD webapp. The add and delete forms are working fine but in edit form in the fields instead of actual value of the field, it is displaying `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0424AA70>` instead of displaying value like John Doe.

I am using python 3.6 and Django 1.10.6

I am using function based approach. So in my views.py, I have following:

```
def proposal_update(request, pk,template_name='proposal/proposal_form.html'):
server = get_object_or_404(Proposal, pk=pk)
form = ProposalForm(request.POST or None, instance=Proposal)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('list')
return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

and in my models.py, I have following:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('proposal_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

and in my urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns=[
  url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ProposalDelete.as_view(),name='proposal_delete'),
  url(r'^new$', views.proposal_create, name='proposal_new'),
  url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.proposal_update, name='proposal_edit'),
]
```

Comment: Use initial data to populate your form.

Comment: Yes, that is the objective, but its not happening. I think its showing initial data but in form of memory strings.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you meant to use the instance, `server`, not the class, Proposal, as the instance value.

```
form = ProposalForm(request.POST or None, instance=server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `initial` keyword to populate your form. Maybe something on this line may help.

```
def proposal_update(request, pk,template_name='proposal/proposal_form.html'):
server = get_object_or_404(Proposal, pk=pk)

data = {'template_field_name': model_field_name}
form = MyForm(initial=data)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('list')
return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```